# Embeding Python Scripts in Wordpress

Tags: python, wordpress

Greetings fellow reader.

I made a python program which runs locally, it takes an .xls file and performs some actions, and finally it exports another .xls file.

These are the libraries:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import os
import openpyxl
from solve import solve_cap
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import cv2
import time
```

Right now, I want to make this program available to be used in a webpage, so anyone can upload an .xls file and will recieve back the modified file, either by mail or a temporary download link.

My problem is that I do not know how I can make this happen, my websites are on wordpress, so I would like to use wordpress in future, but if needed I can change the platform.

The initial idea was to run the script in a virtual environment, create a dedicated e-mail address for the program, and have a contact form on wordpress which sends the necesarry data to the email, after that I would parse the email, take the .xls, perform the necesarry actions and send it back.

Comment: If you are running the script locally only you can just connect to your wordpress folders using FTP.

Answer (score 2):

Well, Wordpress is written in PHP so that's going to be a bit of a problem. However, there are other solutions:

- You rewrite it in PHP (I suppose you don't want that ;))
- You use your proposed mail solution
- You create a dedicated web service

I'd definitely aim for the dedicated web services. I suppose you're using it as a CLI script? In that case, you need to pack that thing in a web service. There are excellent frameworks out there, such as:

- [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/%20Werkzeug)
- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/%Flask)
- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

I'd check out Flask (which is using Werkzeug in the background), because it's quite simple and straight forward. Just check out their first tutorial and you can see if it fits you. Django is a bit oversized for your use case tbh ;)

From there on, I'd try this:

- Put your XLS converter in a Flask project
- Deploy it on your web server (via uWSGI, see the docs [docs on how to deploy it on a webserver](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#deploying-to-a-web-server))

If you want to do more fancy and you're experienced in PHP, you can also create your own Wordpress "backend" plugin which automatically sends the XLS to your web service via POST (don't need a complicated API here).

If you only need it for the users on the front end, a normal `<form action="{url of your web service}" method="POST">` is enough.

That's my two cents :)

Comment: Here's an example to start (didn't test it): https://gist.github.com/domibarton/df2b7d1135c49dc99622283645f88478

You might want to read the docs, as it has a lot of code snippets / examples. Have a look at templates, static files & file uploads :)

Comment: Hey, thank you very much, I will look into Flask, the thing is that in order to run the script I open a webdriver, hope it supports that.